# visual studio recognizing .asp properly or suggestion for classic asp editor/iDE

Tags: visual-studio-2005, asp-classic

How do I get visual studio 2005 to work best with .asp files?

I used to have this on my old PC but I can't get the settings right.  I exported and important all my old settings and still no dice.

alternatively I think there might be an even better choice for classic asp IDE editor.

It'd be nice to have intellisense, completion, highlighting, stuff like that for ASP (vbscript) *and* css/html at the same time.

(I'm happy not to type out css selectors)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

theres probably some bbetter editor but i use Dreamweaver and its working great (changing colors on the keywords and stuff) as for VS i cant help much

Comment: I am agree with that, dreamweaver is the best for asp developpement

Answer (score 0):

I tried using vs2005 for our classic asp application but I wound up going to vs2008. It was a bit of a hastle to get it set up but after I finally did it's been working pretty well.